# How to develop cross-platform mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile, frameworks, cross-platform

So I'm trying to develop a mobile app. I'm new to this and I'm very confused as to how to make an application cross-platform. Is there a way for me to write the code once and make it usable by IOS and Android users? If so, what tools do you recommend to go about doing this? I'm been researching it and I'm not getting a clear cut answer anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: Good question, but too broad for stackoverflow. Keep searching and you will find lots of opinions and articles that will give you more info than you ever wanted. :)

Comment: As mentioned in the answers there are lots of framework available . but you need to figure out which suits your requirement best and easily

Answer (score 3):

React Native is widely used, widely supported solution to make cross platform native applications. Quoting React Native's own website: 

 `"A React Native app is a real mobile app. The apps you are building with React Native aren't mobile web apps because React Native uses the same fundamental UI building blocks as regular iOS and Android apps. Instead of using Swift, Kotlin or Java, you are putting those building blocks together using JavaScript and React."`

Another selling point for React Native is that 

`"React Native combines smoothly with components written in Swift, Java, or Objective-C. It's simple to drop down to native code if you need to optimize a few aspects of your application"`

And then of course React Native is used by **Facebook,Instagram,Uber,Skype,Tesla,Bloomberg,Pinterest**. I have used it personally for personal and professional projects.

**But it all depends on if you already know javascript.**

Answer (score 1):

There is many frameworks that do that, some of the most used ones are [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/), [Xamarin](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/xamarin/) and [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)

I never used any of them, but you can find more about the caracteristics of each one on the web. Keep in mind that all of them will have some drawbacks compared to a true native solution.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin also support Crass Platform Application Development

[source](https://medium.com/@wise4rmgodadmob/create-your-first-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile-application-in-android-studio-e79b855a030b)